# Android ActionBar styling with ActionBar style generator

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using this [ActionBar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to style the `ActionBar`. I have copied the style file and the drawables into the respective folders. But when I try to run the app the following error appears.

This is the `style.xml` file. The error appears after I add this. I am assigning this theme to an activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Example" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Example</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_example</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
    </style>
    <style name="PopupMenu.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DropDownListView.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DropDownNav.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_example</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ProgressBar.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_example</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_example</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The error I got is:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
```

Please help me. This issue is driving me nuts!

Comment: Check the `xmlns:android` directives in every XML files in your Android project. Could be a typo somewhere.

Comment: I checked each and every xml file xmlns:android is fine
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: Then check other namespaces that you might have defined in your XML files that are incorrect. Also, check for secondary namespaces that you might have defined e.g. with menu structure. Lastly, check for missing closing XML tags.

Comment: Show us your code. It will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you declare the `parent` tag with `@android:style`, you need to change it to `@style`. For example:

```
parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
```

Should change to:

```
parent="@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
```

Make the same change as above to other styles that you have declared in your `styles.xml` file.

**Tip**: If you are using `Eclipse` to develop Android, press **Ctrl+Left-Click** at the same time on a `parent` tag to show the style's definition. If the style is defined correctly, pressing  Ctrl+Left-Click will open the corresponding Android's `styles.xml` file. If the `styles.xml` file is not opened after you Ctrl+Left-Click on it, then you know you have a problem with your Android's tag declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's useful to know when developing `Android` in `Eclipse`.